# Finding the volume of revolution of the curve r=2+3cosθ about the initial line?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, volume, curves

]So what I've done is take find the derivative of r wrt θ and use that in the equation for volume,

i.e volume of revolution = $$ \int{2\over 3} r^3 sinθ dθ$$

after substituting $ t=2+3cosθ $ I get 
 $$ \int{2\over 3}  {t^3\over-3} dt$$

with the limits from 0 to π in the first case and 5 to -1 in the second case I get the answer as ${104π\over 3}$

Am I doing this right? I feel like there's something really wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by initial line?

Comment: Do you mean the "polar axis" ?

Comment: The x axis ,i.e the line θ=0